# How do I wrap/unwrap text in a table in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

Apologies but this is driving me crazy

I just want to unwrap the text in this cell so that it is on one line.

How is this done in Google Docs? I don't see the button for it

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To do this, just stretch the cell right to fit by hovering your mouse over the cell border on the right, then left click and drag the cell to the right.  If the line doesn't unwrap, backspace at the beginning of each lower line until it pops to the top line.

Answer (score -1):

The column width display wraps to the narrowest possible width only on my phone, not on my desktop.
To correct this:
In at least one cell in the column, type a string that does not contain any spaces or hyphens until it is the width you prefer.
For example, in a column of time ranges including:

```
10a-3p
```

Change this one to:

```
10a_3p
```

Or, at the top of the column, you could type something like:

```
TimeRanges
```

It is only necessary to do this in one row.